# How can I add a time series animation in GeoVista python?

Tags: python, vtk, netcdf, python-xarray, pyvista

I have this plot created in the GeoVista library.

```
import xarray as xr
import geovista as gv
from geovista.pantry import oisst_avhrr_sst
import geovista.theme
import numpy as np

dataset = xr.open_dataset('temp.nc', decode_times=False)
print(dataset)

x = dataset['LON1_4501'].values
y = dataset['LAT'].values
z = dataset['WATER_TEMP'].values[0, 0, :, :]

mesh = gv.Transform.from_1d(x, y, data=z)


plotter = gv.GeoPlotter()

plotter.add_mesh(mesh)
plotter.orbit_on_path()
plotter.add_base_layer(texture=gv.blue_marble())
plotter.add_coastlines()
plotter.view_xz()
plotter.add_axes()
plotter.show()
```

How can I add a time-series animation to this based on different time values in our dataset?